# Microsoft Office 2011 interface blurred on Retina display

Tags: ms-office, resolution

I am using Microsoft Office 2011 Suite on my MacBook Pro with Retina Display.

The user interfaces are super blur as shown below.

[image]

[image]

Am I missing out some patches or paddings or MS Office does not support retina display at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://blog.officeformac.com/retina-display-support-is-here-for-office-for-mac-2011/), they've supported Retina Display since version 14.2.4. If you are using an older version of Office 2011, then you should upgrade.

Comment: Even after updating to the latest version you might still find some Windows and text are still low resolution and I think Microsoft just needs to do something about that. I've noticed this issue on my Retina as well.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Version itself which can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/mac/downloads at the bottom of the website. Download and update it and it should go back to normal.